# Hibernate not updating when using attribute converters from another POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a funny situation, in my opinion at least.

In hibernate, I have an entity like this, with attribute skipped for brevity

```
public class WobbleEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    @Converter(...) private Wrapper1 wrapper1;
    @Converter(...) private Wrapper2 wrapper2;
}
```

I also have a POJO which contains some elements of that entity;

```
public class Wobbler {
    private Integer id;
    private Wrapper1 wrapper1;
    private Map<String,String> data;
}
```

I've been mapping the two together, using some mapping logic, the mapping logic looks like this:

```
entity.setWrapper2(new Wrapper2(wobbler.getData()));
entity.setWrapper1(wobbler.getWrapper1());
```

My codebase has two types of operations, one that modifies the data attribute of wobbler and the other modifiers the contents of `Wrapper1`.  The operation that modifies the data object has been persisting correctly.  However, the operation that modifies the contents of `wrapper1` in this case was not persisting.  Turning on debug shows that no updates are being called.  When I changed my mapper logic to use

```
entity.setWrapper1(new Wrapper1(wobbler.getWrapper1()));
```

Everything worked perfect.  Last I checked, attribute converted classes aren't treated as managed.  I've correctly implemented `hashcode` and `equals` on the class so doubt that it's an identity issue, so wondering if any one else has seen this and knows why hibernate is doing this?  I'm using the `EntityManager` entry points from JPA.

Comment: Have you found solution yet? I am also currently using this workaround with setting new instance, but it is very ugly to handle all circumstances wherever is used the converted property. I was trying at least somehow to make it automatically in @PreUpdate or setXXX() methods, but did not work for me.

Comment: I raised a bug w/ hibernate, its supposed fixed with 5.0.2.  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10111 There are many work arounds, including just marking the POJO serializable.